# SQL calculate and update columnwise

Tags: sql, t-sql

I hava a stored procedure looking like this:

```
BEGIN
Update  Materials
SET     used_last= 
(       
    Select  
            SUM( Amount*used_last)
    FROM    Used_Materials, 
            Materials, 
            PCNs 
    WHERE   Material_NR=@MatNr 
            AND Used_Materials.Material_NR=Materials.Material_NR 
            AND PCNs.Material_NR=@MatNr 
)
FROM    Materials, 
        PCNs
WHERE   Materials.Material_NR=@MatNr 
        AND PCNs.Material_NR=@MatNr
END
```

This procedure has to be called for each Material (MatNr). Is it possible to perform this Operation for all entires at once? I have stumbled across CURSORs and MAX Case but i cannot get my head around it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you don't `JOIN` the origin table and just leave out the `WHERE` clause, since you want to update all entries anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You desperately need to learn how to use the `JOIN` keyword and to qualify all column names.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

I think this is the query that you want:

```
UPDATE  m
    SET used_last = (SELECT SUM(Amount) * used_last
                     FROM Used_Materials um
                     WHERE um.Material_NR = m.Material_NR 
                    )
    FROM Materials m JOIN
         PCNs
         ON m.Material_NR = PCNs.Material_NR;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i get the Followig error:Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.  Amount is a column of Materials and used_last is a column of UsedMaterials

Comment: I figured it out : SUM(Amount)*used_last